# Need Help in adding I.D from excel into the sql table, is there any way to match the right row and add it in correct ine

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns
ID, First Name, Last Name.

In SQL i have a table that has the above 3 columns and others the ID field is empty, what i'm trying to accomplish is adding the ID from the excel into the sql table, is there a way to match the right row and add it in the correct row? (The excel file does not contain the exact same list as the sql)

Someone help me please  ,  i  am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tend to do is to either import the Excel sheet into a new table on the SQL server or create a script in which I use a table variable and fill it with insert statements created in Excel and copied to the SQL script. After that it is just T-SQL statements that you have to work with, which makes it a lot easier to link the Excel data to the SQL table. Matching records on first and last names is of course less than ideal, but it should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: I have both as a table in mysql, i use phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to excel directly via ADO database connection.

The connectionstring should be like:
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=location of the excel workbook;

Excel behaves like a normal table and you can use e.g. a query with:
insert into tab1 select fieldlist where x = y

Comment: I have both as a table in mysql, i use phpmyadmin. What i can do here.

Comment: please look here for further help: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm

A problem remains in your data: what if two different person has the same first name and lastname. You will maybe assign thre wrong ID. So my recommendation is to create a complete new database with an unique identification for each person (its worth when you have less than 500 entries)